# Favicon is not displayed only at one page in firefox

Tags: firefox, grails, favicon

I have template for all my pages. 
In this template I show a favicon with this code:

```
<r:external uri="/images/favicon.ico"/>
```

In static html it generates the following code:

```
<link href="<somelink>.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
```

In Chrome favicon.ico shown correctly for all pages, but in Firefox only at one page not shown. This page is no different from the rest.

Does anyone have idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Firefox is sensitive to back slash instead of forward slash. Check the page for any of those

Comment: Thanks for advice, but it did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define the `<base>` tag :

like this:

```
<html>
   <title>THE TITLE</title>
   <base href="http://YOUR_URL.COM"/>
   ........
</html>
```